# Ajuda em Mysql PhpMyAdmin Como inserir uma tabela em um banco?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, tabela-banco-de-dados, xampp

Como faço para inserir uma tabela em um abanco ? Sou usuário iniciante de mysql e iniciante no mundo da programação.

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
INSERT INTO banco1(

CREATE TABLE Cliente (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    nome varchar(60)NOT NULL DEFAULT vazio, 
    sexo ENUM('M','F'),
    data_de_nascimento date,
    limite_de_credito decimal(9,2),
    cidade varchar(50),
    bairro varchar(50)
    PRIMARY KEY(id), 
    INDEX(nome) ))
    ENGINE=INNODB   Charset= utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

> Obtive o seguinte ERRO:

**Erro
Análise estática:**
2 erros foram encontrados durante análise.

```
Palavra-chave inesperada. (near "ENGINE" at position 311)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "ENGINE" at position 311)

Comando SQL: 
INSERT INTO banco1( CREATE TABLE Cliente ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT nome varchar(60)NOT NULL DEFAULT vazio, sexo ENUM('M','F'), data_de_nascimento date, limite_de_credito decimal(9,2), cidade varchar(50), bairro varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(nome) )) ENGINE=INNODB Charset= utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT 
Mensagens do MySQL :  
#1046 - Nenhum banco de dados foi selecionado
```

Comment: Clica no banco de dados e depois sim executa a consulta.

Comment: Preciso fazer isso pelo código. É atividade de estudo. Aí preciso saber como faz para o caso de eventuais provas discursivas no decorrer do ano.

Comment: Antes do insert coloca um `use nome do banco;`

Comment: Boa cara ! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `INSERT` é utilizado para inserir dados em tabelas, não tabelas em bancos. Se deseja utilizar determinado banco utilize o comando `USE`.

Ao invés de:

```
    INSERT INTO banco1 ... ;
```

Troque por:

```
    USE banco1; 
    CREATE TABLE ... ;
```

Comment: Entendi. EU errei isso aí mesmo o ";" e o "USE"